# boost::string_ref is slower than std::string copy

Tags: c++, string, optimization, boost, profiling

I have implemented an algorithm 1) using ordinary string copy and 2) with boost::string_view to lookup a suffix part of a string after a delimiter. I have profiled the code and counter-intuitively, I have ended up seeing the boost::string_view performed poorly.

```
std::string algorithm1(const std::string &mine, const std::string& path) {
    size_t startPos = mine.find(path);
    std::string temp;
    if (startPos != mine.npos) {
        startPos += path.size();
        temp = mine.substr(startPos);
    } else {
        std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
        return "";
    }
    return temp;
}

boost::string_ref algorithm2(boost::string_ref mine, boost::string_ref path) {
    size_t startPos = mine.find(path);
    boost::string_ref temp;
    if (startPos != mine.npos) {
        startPos += path.size();
        temp = mine.substr(startPos);
    } else {
        std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
    }
    return temp;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "entered" << std::endl;
    const std::string mine = "sth/aStr/theSuffixWeDesire";
    const std::string path = "/aStr/";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        assert (algorithm1(mine, path) == "theSuffixWeDesire");
        assert (algorithm2(mine, path) == "theSuffixWeDesire");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I have profiled the code with uftrace, I ended up with, for each iteration:
algorithm1 taking 2,083 ns, internally calls std::find
algorithm2 taking 11,835 ns with maximum time spent in calling std::search
Possibly, there could be three reasons I could think of:

1. CPU cache hit in algorithm1, whereas algorithm2 calling boost
   library and therefore CPU cache miss and resulted lower speed
2. Std operations are optimized by the compiler whereas boost operations
   are not.
3. std::search that boost uses is not a good substitute for
   std::find.

Which of these explanations are more plausible? This have been an unexpected behavior, made me doubt using boost::string_ref in my codebase.
My system has gcc 5.4.0 (C++14), boost 1.66, no compiler optimization flags (beginning with -O).

Thank you,

Comment: `no compiler optimization flags (beginning with -O).` Well, that explains it.

Comment: There is no point benchmarking unoptimised code, functions not being inlined will make a huge performance difference

Comment: _"no compiler optimization flags (beginning with -O)"_ Why not? What that actually does isn't "turning off extra optimizations", but "asking the compiler to produce the worst code it is capable of, for easier debugging". And what "worst code" means in practice will differ between different parts of your program. Turn those flags back on for meaningful results!

Comment: Profiling code without optimizations make no sense.

Comment: "Profiled unoptimized code" deserves to be a close reason on its own.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's meaningless to profile unoptimized code.